# Magento special view for special product

Tags: magento-1.9

I know I could edit common product view in `theme-folder/template/catalog/product/*`, what I need is when visit a special product, the product page show a special view, not the common style.

Anyone could give some suggestion to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open admin > open your special product > design > Select your custom design and pay layout > Save.